# How to fetch records for json in array using php?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, rest

```
$emparray=array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_NUM))
    {
        foreach ($row as $key => $value)
        {
            if ($value == '')
            {
                $row[9] ='We follow-up you';
            }
        }
        $emparray[] = array
         ('success' => true,
          'message' => "audio saved Successfully!",
         array('client_cname' => $row[2],
            'future_followup' => $row[8],
            'notes' => $row[9]));             

    }
```

** as you can see above this is my code for fetching records from db using while loop.
problem is im getting all records but with diffrent arrys. i want it in only 1 array with indexes**

```
    [
    {
        "success": true,
        "message": "audio saved Successfully!",
        "0": {
            "client_cname": "Hhhs",
            "future_followup": "4 Jan 2017 05:17 PM",
            "notes": "hey"
        }
    },
    {
        "success": true,
        "message": "audio saved Successfully!",
        "0": {
            "client_cname": "Hcjc",
            "future_followup": "4 Jan 2017 06:17 PM",
            "notes": "hey"
        }
    }
]
```

**above is my O/P**

and i want it in below format please help me with the same.

```
{
    "status": "true",
    "message": "Audio Saved successfully!"
   [
     {
            "client_cname": "Atul",
         “future_followup": “”,
         “notes": “”,
     },
    {
            "client_cname": "Atul",
         “future_followup": “”,
         “notes": “”,
     }
   ]
}
```

**if i remove ->[ ] from $emparray then i will get only last row of table like below code**

```
{
    "success": true,
    "message": "audio saved Successfully!",
    "0": {
        "client_cname": "Hcjc",
        "future_followup": "4 Jan 2017 06:17 PM",
        "notes": "hey"
         }
}
```

**but i want this kind of result with index 0,1,2 and so on.**

please help me with the same. thanks in advance.

Comment: The format you want is not a valid JSON

Comment: ohhh but wt if i want all rows in 1 single array with indexing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you need to do:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) { //if there are any results
  //initialise the array with the first two values
  $emparray = array(
    'success' => true,
    'message' => "audio saved Successfully!");
}

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_NUM))
{
    foreach ($row as $key => $value)
    {
        if ($value == '')
        {
            $row[9] ='We follow-up you';
        }
    }

     //append each data item as an array
     $emparray[] = array('client_cname' => $row[2],
        'future_followup' => $row[8],
        'notes' => $row[9]));             

}
```

This will also automatically index all the other arrays numerically, starting from 0.

Comment: Glad I could help. Bless you!

Answer (score 0):

```
May be this is more better way to deal with.

$dataSet = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
        foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
            if ($value == '') {
                $row[9] = 'We follow-up you';
            }
        }
        $dataSet[] = array('client_cname' => $row[2],
            'future_followup' => $row[8],
            'notes' => $row[9]);
    }

    $emparray = array
    ('success' => true,
        'message' => "audio saved Successfully!",
        'data' => $dataSet);
    echo json_encode($emparray);
```